# Theargument typeListViewFunction(BuildContext,TransactionProvider,Widge)can'tbeassignedtotheparametertype'WidgetFunction(BuildContext,dynamic,Widget?)

Tags: android, flutter, provider, flutter-change-notifier

body: Consumer(
builder: (context, TransactionProvider provider, Widget child) {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: 4, //จำนวนเมนูช่อง 4
itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
return Card(
elevation: 6,
margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
child: ListTile(
//leading: CircleAvatar(
//child: FittedBox
//child: Text("500"),),
title: Text('menu'),
subtitle: Text('1235'),
),
);
});
}

```
    ));
```

}
}

Comment: don't you need to add a question mark after widget here: `Consumer( builder: (context, TransactionProvider provider, Widget child)` so it looks like this: `Consumer( builder: (context, TransactionProvider provider, Widget? child)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.